# Ldap Logout (CakePhp)

Tags: php, cakephp, ldap

I´m currently working on a Login Script with LDAP in cakephp. The login already works fine, but I´m not sure how to realize the logout. 
As far a I know a logout in Ldap has to be done with the method `ldap_unbind`. The method expects one parameter which is returned by the method `ldap_connect` which is located in the login-method.
The problem is that I´m not sure how to pass this parameter from the login-method to the logout-method. I already tried to transfer it through a session, but that didn´t work as expected.
Does anyone have any idea how to transfer it? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Did you tried LDAP logout method ? What do you actually want ? Do you want to logout your application ? You have mention about pass the parameter , for logout you don't need pass parameter.

Comment: Which logout method do you mean?
Actually I´m checking with Ldap if the user exists and has accessrights to the folder. If the user is allowed, I´m logging in the user with the cakephp component `auth`. When the user logs out I´m logging out with cakephp´s `auth` but I also want to logout the user with ldap. I thought this was possible with `ldap_unbind`. Or is this not necessary?

Comment: ah ok. now I know which logout method you are talking about. But this is the classic cakephp auth logout right? It´s not really logging out from LDAP right? Or is it not necessary to logout with ldap? Sorry, first time I work with this.

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I misunderstood the way of logging in with ldap. Thanks for your help!